# How to reload item of combobox in c#?

Tags: c#, select, combobox, reload

I have 10 items in combobox and when I delete one of those items, the combobox don't show automatically next item it show white space. I want to display next item in range.

I delete them normaly

`cmbsomename.Items.Remove(cmbsomename.SelectedItem);`

How to do that?

Comment: How are you deleting them because that will determine how to pick next item in items?

Answer (score 5):

Because you deleted the selected item, you need to set another item as selected:

```
comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

**Edit:**

The code above sets the selected item as the first item in the list.
For the next item, you need to find the index of the item you are deleting first:

```
int index = cmbsomename.SelectedIndex;
cmbsomename.Items.Remove(cmbsomename.SelectedItem);

if (index < cmbsomename.Items.Count) // Make sure there IS a next item
   cmbsomename.SelectedIndex = index; // Next item will have same index value
```

Comment: OP said next item not first item.

Answer (score 1):

after deleting an Item set the selectedindex

```
int index = comboBox.SelectedIndex;
comboBox.Items.Remove(comboBox.SelectedItem);

if (index < comboBox.Items.Count) 
   comboBox.SelectedIndex = index;
```

Comment: OP said next item not first item.

Answer (score 1):

```
var selectedIndex = cmbsomename.SelectedIndex;
cmbsomename.Items.Remove(cmbsomename.SelectedItem);
comboBox.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex < cmbsomename.Items.Count() ? ++selectedIndex : 0;
```